# How To Add Image To UISegmentedControl Text On a Side

Tags: ios5, uiimageview, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add UIImageView along with text for `UISegmentedControl`. Please Note that I don't want to set image as background and I have already got segmented control in IB. What I have tried so far is:

```cs
for (id segment in [segmentControl subviews]) 
    {
        for (id label in [segment subviews]) 
        {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                float width = ((UILabel*)label).bounds.size.width;
                UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow-down.png"]];
                image.frame = CGRectMake(width + 2, 15 , 32, 32);

                ((UILabel*)label).frame = CGRectMake(((UILabel*)label).frame.origin.x,((UILabel*)label).frame.origin.y, width + image.frame.size.width + 5, ((UILabel*)label).frame.size.height);
                [(UILabel*)label insertSubview:image atIndex:0];
            }
        }           
    }
```

Please can someone guide me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can directly set backgoundcolor of uilabel

```
((UILabel*)label).backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrow-down.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have mentioned in my Question that I don't want to set image as background. I want image at end of the end of UILabel text.